# Why doesn't class attribute remember values added via __iadd__ method?

Tags: python, class, addition

I've got some short class `Car`:

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, brand, model, color, accesories):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.accesories = ['radio']

    def __str__(self):
        return " accessories {}".format(self.accesories)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.accesories.extend(other)
        print(self.accesories)
        return Car(self.brand, self.model, self.color, self.accesories)
```

I create an object with:

```
car1 = Car('opel','astra','blue',[])
```

When I try to add additional accessories with:

```
car1 += ['wheel']
```

It prints:

```
['radio', 'wheel']
```

But when I later call:

```
car1.accesories
```

or

```
print(car1)
```

it gives me, respectively:

```
['radio']
```

and

```
accessories ['radio']
```

Why does object not remember values added to list?

Comment: You are returning a new `Car`. Make the method return `self`.

Comment: You are always initializing with self.accesories = ['radio'], try with default value at the __init__(a,b,c,accesories=['radio'])

Comment: Or just return self

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you have:

```
return Car(self.brand, self.model, self.color, self.accesories)
```

in your `__iadd__` method, which will reset `self.accessories` back to `['radio']` from the `__init__`:

```
self.accesories = ['radio']
```

The operation:

```
car1 += ['wheel']
```

sets the value returned from `__iadd__` method as name `car1` with the `accessories` being set from `__init__` as `['radio']` hence you'll get `['radio']` when accessing `car1.accessories`.

---

Perhaps you wanted to use the value of parameter `accessories` as the attribute:

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, brand, model, color, accesories=None):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.accesories = accessories if accessories else ['radio']
```

Comment: Yes now it works , that was exatly that problem, i forgot that the object is new initialized. Thank a lot

Answer (score 2):

You returned a newly-initialized object, rather than the one you just updated.  Replace your long `return` with simply

```
return self
```

Output:

```
['radio', 'wheel']
 accessories ['radio', 'wheel']
```